# Stack Exchange page opens when opening the "Inbox" on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, bug

Today I ran into a weird "error" on the Stack Overflow site.

I added the page via bookmark on Chrome. This could possibly be relevant as well.

I'm not entirely sure, but to me, it seems like a bug, since Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are two different sites or show other information.

**How can I reproduce the problem?**

Open the Stack Overflow page and click on your "Inbox" as soon as you can see it.

**What should happen? What actually happens?**

A smaller window of your messages should open, but here the inbox of Stack Exchange opens. You will see all the information there, but not the messages specific to Stack Overflow.

**A video of the mentioned behavior:**

https://i.imgur.com/M9X6J1c.mp4 (Sorry, there is no way to embed videos)

Is this intentional?

Comment: Stackexchange is the default click action for that, prior to scripts running and taking it's place. It links to your global inbox. It's been doing this for long enough that it must be intentional.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for the "possible" clarification, I can not explain otherwise, but have rather asked here once

Comment: I wonder if there was a recent change that caused js to load slower because I've also been experiencing this a lot lately.